# Having problems with datepicker

Tags: java

In my Java netbean program, I'm having problems with my project when i type ***datepicker. setDate(null);*** then I have an error, showing a `redline`under the datepicker. Is there any import for datepicker? How can I fix this?

Comment: How is `datepicker` defined?

Comment: Anyway, if it is declared as a JavaFX [`DatePicker`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html) you need to import `javafx.scene.control.DatePicker`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca javaDoc doesn't seem to know about a setDate() on that class.

Comment: @scratte than it's not that one. Thanks for pointing it out